# Error con consulta a API para interpretar texto en Xamarin con c#

Tags: api, xamarin.forms

El error se presenta al momento de mandar el request al API, me dice que el error esta en la caratula, según dice el instructivo del API Tienes un error tipográfico en las cabeceras que envías.

FUNCION EN EL BOTON PARA RECOLECTAR EL TEXTO E INGRESARLO EN EL REQUEST

````
```private async void interpretar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ //formato que solicita el API
    var interpreter = new TextInterpreter();
    var request = new API 
    { 
        max_tokens = 512,
        model = "chat-sophos-1",
        n = 1,
        source_lang = "es",
        target_lang = "es",
        temperature = 0.7,
        text = txtdiagnostico.Text //ingreso de texto en formulario
    };
    try
    {
        var response = await interpreter.InterpretTextAsync(request);
        interpretLabel.Text = response.interpreted_text;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        interpretLabel.Text = $"Error en la solicitud a la API: {ex.Message}";
    }

}```
````

EN LA CLASE API TENGO LA CONEXION A LA API Y EL CONVERSOR A FORMATO JSON

el error que da en pantalla es BadRequest, pero no sale el porque, pero mitigando los otros causas este es la unica posible [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
```public class API //declaracion de variables
 {
     public int max_tokens { get; set; }
     public string model { get; set; }
     public int n { get; set; }
     public string source_lang { get; set; }
     public string target_lang { get; set; }
     public double temperature { get; set; }
     public string text { get; set; }
 }

 public class TextInterpretationResponse
 {
     public string interpreted_text { get; set; }
 }

 public class TextInterpreter
 {
     private readonly string apiUrl = "apiurl"; //claves para acceder
     private readonly string apiKey = "apikey";

     public async Task<TextInterpretationResponse> InterpretTextAsync(API request)
     {
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
         {
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {apiKey}");

             var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request); //conversor a json
             var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

             var response = await client.PostAsync(apiUrl, content);

             if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
             {
                 var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 var interpretation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TextInterpretationResponse>(jsonResponse);
                 return interpretation;
             }
             else
             {
                 // Manejar el error de la API aquí
                 throw new Exception($"{response.StatusCode}");
             }
         }
     }
 }```
````